# Pipenv is inaccurate in installing dependencies

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

I need torch/torchvision/torchaudio and associated dependencies for a project. I'm using `pipenv` in order to track the python dependencies, and hopefully be able to send things to other people and have them install everything with a simple `pipenv install`. I installed the torch stuff with pipenv as per [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4961), substituting `--index` for `--extra-index-url` from Arcitec's accepted answer, which I believe is now necessary due to pip-env updates. However, a script I'm running in this environment is failing due to an inability to import a package called `charset-normalizer`.

pipenv claims that charset-normalizer is installed, from the `pipenv graph` feature(excerpt pasted here).

```
torchvision==0.15.2+cu118
├── numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.26.3]
├── pillow [required: >=5.3.0,!=8.3.*, installed: 10.2.0]
├── requests [required: Any, installed: 2.31.0]
│   ├── certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2023.11.17]
│   ├── charset-normalizer [required: >=2,<4, installed: 2.0.12]
│   ├── idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.6]
│   └── urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<3, installed: 2.1.0]
```

However, charset-normalizer is also not in the virtual environment `site-packages` location, gotten from `pipenv --venv`, where all the other packages seem to be. Additional attempts to install `charset-normalizer` with `pipenv install charset-normalizer`, also come up with claimed success, and no appearance of `charset-normalizer` alongside the other packages.

I can see the charset_normalizer folder in the `site-packages` of like all my pip installed stuff, and was anticipating a similar looking folder existing in the `site-packages` of the pipenv installed virtual environment. But it is not, despite `pipenv` claiming it is there. Is pipenv trying to point to my existing version? Wouldn't that defy the point of a virtual environment? Any help would be appreciated.
I'm on windows unfortunately, if that's helpful.

UPDATE: It seems I could get around this with `pipenv install chardet`, as the ML library(whisper) seemed able to target that instead for some reason(chardet and charset-normalizer seem to server similar purposes). I'm still fascinated by how pipenv claimed that I had charset-normalizer installed and didn't actually seem to have charset-normalizer installed. There was even a bunch of hashes in the `Pipfile.lock` that were supposed to correspond to different versions of charset-normalizer I believe, but still no charset-normalizer on my machine. I'd be grateful for any explanation of what went on there!